# Need a new virtual property that returns value based upon two physical properties

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a couple of basic table in my database that store names as FirstName and LastName. Almost every table that has a person's name, it is being stored as FirstName and LastName. Now while I LINQ my way through the application, I realize that I am constantly using the combination in `.Where()` and `.OrderBy()` and I’m wondering if I can inject a method into the DBContext that can return me `FirstName + " " + LastName` as *FullName* column for all such entities (tables)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on appropriate .dbml file and select View Code. You should see a partial class created for you for the table. In that class add a new property that just returns the full name.

public string FullName
{
    get { return this.FirstName + this.LastName; }
}

You will then be able to access FullName everywhere in the code.

Comment: its partial so can i add in my own partial class? I dont wanna re-wrtie it again as I update diagram over and over.

Comment: Okay. Added a new file under the Context and manged to add a new class and made it partial. Repeated for all the required entities. Now looking at a huge set of Find results where I now need to use the virtual FullName property lol.

Comment: Right...when you update the diagram, it would update the other partial class file and not yours, so it won't overwrite your code. You may want to try updating your diagram and making sure it does not overwrite your code, just to make sure you put the code in right place, before you make lot of code changes. You shouldn't have had to create this partial class manually....when you click View Code, it should have created this class file for you.

Comment: Problem: The member 'ExciteEngine2.DAL.Locum.FullName' has no supported translation to SQL.' I'm suing it in linq queries to DB. The exception makes sense. Work-around, anyone?

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do. Based on that, replace that property you added with the following and it should work.

public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<_YourTableName_, string>> FullName()
{
 return (table => table.FirstName + " " + table.LastName);
}

Comment: Alrighty. I'll make the changes. Can we use String.Format() there? `return (table => table.FirstName + " " + table.LastName);` becomes `return (table => String.Format("{0} {1}", table.FirstName , table.LastName));` ? Also, why so `static`?

Comment: Damn: `Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property` error started to appear now. Here is a snip: `from coord in DbContext.ClientCoordinators
 where coord.ClientID == Branch.ClientID
 orderby coord.FirstName, coord.LastName
 select new {
  coord.OID,
  CoordinatorName = coord.FullName
 };`

Comment: It could be one of two things:
1) FullName is now a method so you would have to do CoordinatorName = coord.FullName().
2) FirstName or LastName cannot be null. If it is, initialization of anonymous type would fail and you would get the error. Hope it helps.

Comment: My DB doesn't allow for FirstName or LastName to be null. So that's covered. However, I'm not able to access the `.FullName()` method. Can anyone help?